# Convert Elasticsearch JSON query into C# NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an Elasticsearch database and I have an index `test`

Here the schema:

```
PUT test
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "channel" : {
            "properties" : {
                "id" : { "type" : "integer" },
                "name" : { "type" : "string" }
            }
        },
        "segment" : {
            "properties" : {
                "groupid" : { "type" : "text", "fielddata": true  },
                "instrName" : { "type" : "text", "fielddata": true },
                "channelList" : { "type" : "object" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to convert this query into C# NEST code:

```
 GET /test/segment/_search
    {
      "aggs": {
        "agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "instrName"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg2": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "groupid"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

I know how to convert a single aggregation query but not a nested aggregation

**EDIT**

Here the current code but I get a 500 error from ES

```
    var res = elastic.Search<SegmentRecord>(
        s => s.Index(esIndex).Aggregations(a => a.Terms("instrName", x => x.Aggregations(w => w.Terms("groupid", sel => sel)))));
```

Comment: Can you show us your existing C# code?

Comment: Take a look at the nested aggregation usage example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nested-aggregation-usage.html

Comment: @mjwills just did. please have a look, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the field that each [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-aggregation-usage.html) should run on. A `terms` aggregation with a `terms` sub aggregation looks like

```
var res = elastic.Search<SegmentRecord>(s => s
    .Index(esIndex)
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("agg", t => t
            .Field("instrName")
            .Aggregations(sa => sa
                .Terms("agg2", tt => tt
                    .Field("groupid")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```